# Namespaced kubernetes operator for multiple namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-operator, operator-sdk, kubebuilder

I am thinking about using `cluster` vs `namespaced` scope k8s operators.

In theory i have a lot of namespaces and i can deploy some kubernetes operator `KO` for each namespace. I suppose that in this case in each namespace `KO` subscribed for events in kubernets cluster for each namespace. Сould this be a performance problem for the cluster? Maybe for big number of namespaces is better idea to use cluster scope operator ? (It manage many instances for many namespaces but have only one subscription)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**"Namespace-scoped" points to the custom resource handled by the operator, rather than the operator itself.** One operator in the cluster can handle both namespace-scoped resources and cluster-scoped resources, so there is no need to distribute an operator deployment to many namespaces.

[Here](https://sdk.operatorframework.io/docs/building-operators/golang/operator-scope/) you can find more information about operator scopes.